# How to define an array of strings, with assignment split from defining?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I want to define an array of strings, with defining and assignment splitted in two lines like the following:

```
char **test;
test = { "Snakes", "on", "a", "Plane" }; // <--
printf("Test: %s\n", test[3]);
```

But I get an error in the indicated line:

```
Line 4: error: expected expression before '{' token
```

What is wrong here? Is there a good tutorial on explaining all the arrays, pointers, declaration, definition, assignment of and between C strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assigning an array by this way.
In your case your array is not allocated.

The way to do this is :

```
char    *test[4];

test[0] = "Snake";
test[1] = "on";
test[2] = "a";
test[3] = "plane";
```

Comment: I asked specifically how this can be done with declaration and assignment SEPARATED.

Answer (score 2):

it cannot write only in the initialization expression of a C99 before

E.g.

```
char *test[]={ "Snakes", "on", "a", "Plane" };
```

It can be written as follows in C99

E.g.

```
char **test;
test = (char*[]){ "Snakes", "on", "a", "Plane" };
```

Comment: Sorry, for this solution I get a warning `assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Werror]` which is not acceptable.

Comment: Do you compile in C99 mode? i.e. `-std=c99` in case of gcc.

Comment: @Alex Use the c99 compiler support. e.g. `gcc prog.c -std=c99`

Comment: I am afraid I cannot change the compiler settings. I have to use the compiler modes as they are.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it like this.

Either, as pointed above, do it at declaration.

Either use a built-in functuin (strcpy, memcpy) for each word.

Best way would be to make a function that adds the respective word(s) to your array using the functions above or char by char.